# Exporting shapefiles as SVG polylines

Tags: qgis, line, svg, polyline-creation, path

Recently I've been using QGIS to create fracture tracemaps as line shapefiles. I need to export these lines as an SVG that uses the tag polylines rather than paths. I've used the SimpleSVG plugin but this seems to export as paths. 
I've also tried importing this into Adobe Illustrator and exporting again but this still only recognizes paths.

Does anyone have any advice on how to handle this?

I'm very new to any kind of coding so I'd preferably like to not have to manually edit the SVG file myself, and don't have enough experience to create code to edit the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export to DXF from QGIS

[image]

Open DXF in Adobe Illustrator (v24.0.2 used)

[image]

Export to SVG (but **Inline Style** mode)

[image]

SVG Code with Polylines
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This has worked perfectly.